# Prepared data with swapping or multiple joins each time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please, let me explain it with an example:

*You need to show actual information to a customer about the price of some product. The final price is influenced by customer privelege, his location, way to ship the product and vendor of current product.*

*Amount of products is above 10 billion. Besides you should show the price in different currency. And the final problem is, that vendors send every day lots of prices on their products, which you able to apply (update) whithin whole day due to a lot of positions there, while customers don't want to wait until you update all of them and want to know current price (I know this is impossible, but what I mean - is that a customer shouldn't see messages like this: "Sorry, you have to wait until all the prices are updated").*

**What do I want**

I want to divide one table `ThePrice (productId, vendorId, usdPrice)`, which is used each time a customer makes a query like that

```
select .... from ThePrice p
  inner join Vendors v ...
  inner join VendorsPrices vp ...
  inner join UserRatio ur ...
  left join ShippingRatio ...
  inner join Currencies ...
  inner join PriceDependsOnLocation ...
```

into two similar tables

`FirstPrice (productId, vendorId, usdPrice, user1Ratio, user2Ratio, user3Ratio, shipppingRatio, euroPrice, localPrice)`

and

`SecondPrice(productId, vendorId, usdPrice, user1Ratio, user2Ratio, user3Ratio, shipppingRatio, euroPrice, localPrice)`.

Where

`userXRatio` - all possible factors for customer privelege level. Additional multiply on the `usdPrice`.
`shippingRatio` - defines does customer needs shipping. Additional multiply on the `usdPrice`.
`euroPrice`,`localPrice` - is the prices to show in different currency with respect to today's quotation.

which might look like

```
if (@OneHourPassed = 1) 
  select ... from FirstPrice
else
  select ... from SecondPrice

--not the best way but just to point out
```

Now all this parameters are recalculated each time, because a price can change on every next query, when it would be updated to `ThePrice` table. There is no cache for that.

This means, that from time to time I receive locks, because while a customer searches for the products, they are being also updated the whole day. Imagine - in a minute there can be 2000 queries from customers and one or two prices from vendors are to be updated. *In the same table!*

I want to use a prepared data: while `FirstPrice` table is used for READ, the `SecondPrice` table is used for WRITE - to update the prices. And in a certain moment they swap, i.e. in an hour.

And I just want to know - what is the mechanism to apply that. Using IF-s? Or is there  another more elegant way?

Comment: Your question is extremely broad and doesn't provide a lot of details about what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I was trying to be as short as possible as people don't have time to read plenty of text. What details you suggest to add to make is more clear and easy?

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounded a litle too out in space, but from what I could capture, maybe something like this could help you.

```
 create table FirstPrice (
    productId int, 
    vendorId int, 
    usdPrice money, 
    user1Ratio int, 
    user2Ratio int, 
    user3Ratio int, 
    shipppingRatio int, 
    euroPrice money, 
    localPrice money
)

 create table SecondPrice (
    productId int, 
    vendorId int, 
    usdPrice money, 
    user1Ratio int, 
    user2Ratio int, 
    user3Ratio int, 
    shipppingRatio int, 
    euroPrice money, 
    localPrice money
)


 CREATE TABLE LastExecution(execDate datetime default getdate());
 insert into LastExecution(execDate) values (default);
 GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_PRICE
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
  SELECT @DATE=EXECDATE FROM LastExecution

  IF (DATEDIFF(HOUR,@DATE,GETDATE())>0) 
    BEGIN
      insert into LastExecution(execDate) values (default);
      SELECT 'Second' as [table],* FROM SecondPrice;
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'First' as [table],* FROM FirstPrice;
    END
END;
```

Comment: Yes, this is it, I think, but I need it also for the rest calculations. I mean I need something like a view, where I can be absolutely sure, that until the X-time only one of two tables would be used (in a plan also). IF-s is okay for a procedure (Should check the plans also). (I'm sorry - my previous version of this topic was including this part of an issue). Any recommendations with this new information? Anyway - thanks!

Comment: Sorrry, this time I really dont understand your question. Can you explain that again?

Comment: I'm saying, that this solution is clear, but I have a bit more complicated situation - there are a lot of procedures, where this kind of query is used. I need something like view or synonims. Truth to say - the last one (synonim) - I don't realy know from where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that a descision is two ways:

1) Using `Partitions`, but with buying Enterprise Edition and I still don't understand the moment for switching tables

2) Using a `View`, which is possible to `Alter`, but you have to make a *Control Table*, where you should hold a flag for switching tables and have this script everywhere in the queries:

```
while exists(select 1 from ControlTable where SwitchNow = 1)
begin
  waitfor delay '00:00:00.005'
end
-- this is for client-queries, who should release the View from being Altered
```

OR another from aside suggested way

```
create table Switch(Part bit not null);
insert Switch values(0)
go
create view PriceView 
with view_metadata
as
select * from Price1 where 1 = (select Part from Switch)
union all
select * from Price2 where 0 = (select Part from Switch)
```

but I think, it is not a good idea for an sql-planner or do I see it wrong? Because if I'm wrong, then it's the best way.